# Problem in getting the path of a shortcut file!

Tags: mfc, filepath

In my application,I have an option of adding files to a list..were it will let the user to select multiple files at the same..am using CFileDialog to do tis and I enabled OFN_MULTISELECT (for multiselect)...The problem am facing is,When I try to add a shortcut file..its not taking the actual shortcut path,its reffering to the actual path.Actually I wanted to avoid shortcut file being added to my list,but every shortcut file that is being added does not have the extension ".lnk"(i dont know the reason).
So,is there any way that we can neglect the shortcut file being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the flag:

```
OFN_NODEREFERENCELINKS = 0x100000;
```

regards
Oops
PS: it does not neglect links from being added, but it ensures to let the link as it is. You will get files with *.lnk extensions for links. afterwards you can filter them out in you code.